# How to Sed or Grep number next to text

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a file like the one below. I want to return the value to the right of info2. Secondly I would want to return the value of info5 in the same manner.

FILE:

```
info1 218, info2 111, info3 415, info5 done,
```

Comment: I think awk is a better tool for this.

Comment: Is `info1` always in the first field? Is `info5` always in the fourth field? How big is the file? Are you going to do this once and then you are done? Or are you going to be repeating it? How often?

Comment: They are not always in the same place unfortunately. I am planning to run this about once an hour for a couple weeks.

Comment: Do they occur on every line (or at least on most lines)? If so, DopeGhoti's solution in a comment below should work fine. If they are very rare, then you might want to run a `grep "info[25]"` in the pipeline instead of his `cat`.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS="," } $1 ~ /info[25]$/ { print $2 }' input
111
done
```

We set the input record separator (`RS`) to the comma, and then for each record in which the first field contains `info` followed by either a two or a five (and nothing else), print the second field.

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement on [choroba’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420776/80216#420777):

```
sed -n 's/.*info2 \([^,]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

- `-n` means “don’t print anything
  except when specifically commanded to do so”. 
  This is (somewhat) equivalent to choroba’s use of `!d`
  to delete (ignore) lines that don’t match `info2`.
- The guts of the command is very similar to choroba’s,
  except it captures a sequence of any characters except commas
  (not just numerals), so it can extract the `done` from `info5 done,`.
- The command ends with `p` (print),
  because otherwise, with the `-n`, nothing would be printed.

This has the advantage that
it doesn’t require specifying the `infoN` label twice. 
(And it doesn’t generate undesired results
if a line contains `info20`, `info21`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A two step solution:

```
tr ',' '\n' <file | sed -n 's/^ *info[25] *//p'
```

The `tr` transforms the example text into

```
info1 218   
 info2 111  
 info3 415  
 info5 done
```

and the `sed` script removes the `info2` and `info5` strings (and any surrounding whitespace), leaving the wanted pieces of text.  The other lines are discarded.

Result:

```
111
done
```

---

This is better done with `awk`, as in [DopeGhoti's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420789/116858).

An `awk` variation based on my `tr` approach:

```
tr ',' '\n' <file | awk '/info[25]/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: you actually don't need tr if you use awk, look at the answer by @DopeGhoti

Comment: @DiegoRoccia I'm well aware of his answer (otherwise I would not link to it). This is a variation an my `sed` solution, and as you can see, it replaces his setting of `RS` with preprocessing the data into newline-delimited records. The two are otherwise the same.

Comment: I agree that the output is the same, but IMO adding useless complexity is not a good variation, so I'm advising not to do it

Answer (score -1):

You can use sed:

```
sed '/info2 [0-9]/!d;s/.*info2 \([0-9]*\).*/\1/' file
```

- `/info2/` is an "address", any line containing `info2` is considered to match the address. `!d` means "delete lines outside of the address", so only lines containing `info2` will be processed by the next command.
- The substitution uses a capture group to remember the number after `info2`, and the whole line (everything before `info2`, `info2` itself, the number, and anything following the number) is replaced by the number.

If you need to capture "done" after `info5`, you can't use `[0-9]*`, but you can replace it by `[^,]*`, i.e. non-comma.

Comment: ... and he wants to do the same thing with info5 (and the value there is not a number).

Comment: @Nick (just to make the answer complete) use `[^,]*` in place of `[0-9]*`, and I agree `awk` is a better fit.

Comment: What would Awk look like and why better?

Comment: This generates undesired results if a line contains `info2` without actually having an `info2` label; e.g., `info20`, `info21`, etc.